# How do I preform a print statement, while calling a function on the same line?

Tags: python, function

I am working on writing a simple program for school where I need to calculate the product of two integers inputted by the user and return the answer. I am wondering how I can print the statement below, with the answer (function) following the semicolon.

```
print("the product of the two integers is: ")

#Calls the function 
multiply()
```

Full program:

```
print("This program will find the product of the two integers you input.")

#Prompts user to enter the first integer they want to multiply
num_one = float(input("Enter the first number you would like to multiply: "))

#Prompts the user to enter the second integer they want to multiply
num_two = float(input("Enter the first number you would like to multiply: "))

#Function to find the product of the two numbers
def multiply():
    return num_one * num_two

print("the product of the two integers is: ")

#Calls the function 
multiply()
```

Comment: `print("the product of the two integers is: ", multiply())`

Comment: @SayandipDutta - and remove the space after the colon because python will add one.

Comment: `result = multiply()` followed by `print(f"the product of the two integers is: {result}")`.

Comment: I think you need to read further in your course work. There's no way this wouldn't be explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, all you need to do is,

```
print("the product of the two integers is: ", multiply())
```

However, you can simplify this to

```
print(f"the product of the two integers is: {num_one*num_two}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("The product of the two integers is: " + str(multiply()))
```